# Laravel 5.2 Fatal error:vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have uploaded my laravel project from `local` to `host`.
Now I have following error:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/httpd/vhosts/mort.com/httpdocs/cucc/testLaravel/vendor/composer/../../app/Libraries/helpers.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/httpd/vhosts/mort.com/httpdocs/cucc/testLaravel/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66`
```

I cannot understand what the problem is. The laravel framework is in the directory called `testLaravel` and the public content in a directory called `laravel`.

Comment: Did you run composer install on the "host"?

Comment: hi troyer, no I did not run composer on the host

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error means some packages are missing, as I see you didn't run `composer install`, this means the required packages are not installed.

To solve it just go to the root of your project and run on the command line:

```
composer install
```

Answer (score 10):

**If the other solutions do not work, you can try:**

1- Delete Composer Folder (vendor/composer)

2- Delete Autoload.php (vendor/autoload.php)

Then, write on the console:

3- Composer Install.

4- Composer Update.

5- And run server.

I hope this can help you.

Bye.

Comment: this solution has worked with me on Magento

Comment: This is the correct answer for the question asked.

Answer (score 5):

For me, only **"composer install"** doesn't' work. After googling I find out a solution which is given below

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

and then

```
composer update
```

**It's worked for me.**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using local composer path type packages and error is due to changing packages folder name then you must delete /vendor/package folder symlinks. Then run "composer update". This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

just delete

1. vendor folder(delete)
2. composer.lock(delete optional)

then run

```
composer install
```

Answer (score 1):

First, delete the vendor folder from the project directory, then type the composer install command. Work fine me.

composer update
composer install
composer diagnose
composer self-update