# Webhost Storage Errors, how to solve

Tags: php, html, apache, web, web-hosting

I am trying to add an application to webhost, and I am receiving the following error:

Warning: require(/storage/ssd1/111/16245111/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /storage/ssd1/111/16245111/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 71

Warning: require(/storage/ssd1/111/16245111/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /storage/ssd1/111/16245111/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 71

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/storage/ssd1/111/16245111/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /storage/ssd1/111/16245111/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 71

Can some of you help me understand and solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.2 Fatal error:vendor/composer/autoload\_real.php on line 66](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47436773/laravel-5-2-fatal-errorvendor-composer-autoload-real-php-on-line-66)

Comment: I will try thank you!